# Previewer not loading <camera> tag in DevEco Studion 3.0.0.900?

Tags: mobile-application, huawei-developers, harmonyos, deveco-studio

I was making some library functions for using the camera in OpenHarmony for the JS API. When I used the  tag in the HML file, the Previewer couldn't load it. Moreover, DevEco Studio 3.0.0.900 doesn't support emulators, so I have no other way to test those functions. How should I deal with this?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a log of the previewer for us to check?

Comment: `[phone][Console    INFO]  05/30 22:55:57 27772  app Log: Application onCreate`. This is the only log statement coming while opening the previewer.

Comment: Choose help > show log, and the previewer.log file will be displayed.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/191Rf1d-8vPR0jaQCYSZl9Rb2ZmsNk9a6/view?usp=sharing) to the previewer.log file up until now.

Comment: Looks like i can't access your log file. can you send your log to hmscore@huawei.com?

Comment: I have sent the file to the address you provided.

Comment: Sorry, the team confirmed that currently camera component do not support preview on the previewer and simulator. You are advised to perform the test on a Real Device.